# why netbeans doesn't show persian characters correctly

Tags: java, file, netbeans

when I read from a .csv file in java

it does its work correctly,

but for not english(persian) chars it show "?"

I add -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to my netbeans_default_options in netbeans.conf

but it is incorrect yet

what should I do?

Comment: If the original .csv is not encoded properly it won't matter which settings you use.  Are you sure it's been written using UTF-8?

Comment: The option you add will only affect the encoding within the NetBeans IDE. When you run your own java code, then this encoding is NOT used. Please fix your code to support UTF-8 - see the code snippet below.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to try `UTF-16` instead of `UTF-8` to display Persian characters.

Here's Joel Spolsky's excellent [blog post](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) on the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use the programmers editor [JEdit](http://jedit.org) to check the encoding (can be started from the web).

Read with

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

This explicitly sets the character encoding, which is better than the global system property file.encoding.

Or try "**ISO-639-3**" instead of "UTF-8".